# Multiple item tax sub-totals are shown incorrectly on confirmation pages and emails

Tags: contributions, receipts, taxes

We have a site with tax and invoicing enabled on contribution settings.
Drupal 7 civi 5.24.6

Where there is just one item to purchase on a page. The totals and subtotals appear as expected...

*Payment amounts from Contribution confirmation page*
[image: contribution page- payments amounts 1 item]

*Payment amounts from confirmation email*
[image: confoirmation email- payment info 1 item]

But when multiple taxable items are available on a contribution page the taxable subtotals show incorrectly...

*Payment amounts from Contribution confirmation page*
[image: contribution page- payments amount 2 items]
Here the total VAT (tax) amount shows as £260, when it should be £520- but both line items show correctly and the Payment Total is the correct overall total

*Payment amounts from confirmation email*
[image: email confoirmation- 2 line items]
The email acknowledgement for these items is even more broken
The amount before tax shows £2860 instead of £2600, basically a tax amount has been added here.
total VAT line is fine at £520, but the Total Tax line is only showing £260

Again the overall total is correct.

Anyone any idea where these different amounts are being drawn from? How to correct this?

Comment: There's been recent work on this area.  I live in a country where most NGOs don't collect tax, but a) try upgrading a test site to CiviCRM 5.27 when it comes out later today and see if it helps; b) ask in the ~financial channel https://chat.civicrm.org; c) tax calculation code is changing in Civi 5.28, you may want to test the release candidate as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is reported at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1603 and there was a [fix](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17610) merged into 5.27 which is scheduled to be out today, unfortunately the [fix](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17610) was [reverted](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17680) since it created regression bug.